# where is tomcat configuration stored in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA ultimate 14 and I'm experiencing a tiny bit of oddness. When I run over IntelliJ I'm seeing everything I would hope/expect to see in my application. But when I build a war file and deploy to my stand-alone tomcat I'm seeing very slight differences. Specifically right now I'm trying to track down why fonts are deploying correctly in the tomcat bundled with IntelliJ, but not in my stand-alone. Both are localhost, by the way.

Can anybody tell me where on the filesystem IntelliJ stores its tomcat configuration (server.xml)? I'd really like to compare the two versions and see if there is anything obviously different.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem well. However, you can check the startup log in IDEA. I think catalina.base is what you want.

`31-Aug-2015 22:44:04.592 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/lhuang/dev/servers/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/endorsed
31-Aug-2015 22:44:04.592 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/lhuang/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/tomcat/Tomcat_8_0_20_FileStorageService_2
31-Aug-2015 22:44:04.592 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/lhuang/dev/servers/apache-tomcat-8.0.20`